# update product using magento 2.2 rest api but result in error %fieldName is a required field

Tags: magento2

i'm  trying to use rest api (magento 2.2.2) to update a custom attribute as the below script

```
$productData =  '{
  "product": {
    "sku": "test1",
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "localisation",
        "value": "Test Description"
      }
    ]
  }
}';                

                $token = getToken();

                $str = "http://m22.example.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/test1";

                $ch = curl_init($str);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($productData));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

                $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

Below is the error which i get :

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["message"]=> string(31) "%fieldName is a required field." ["parameters"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["fieldName"]=> string(7) "product" } ["trace"]=> string(1903) "#0 /home/m22/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->processInputError(Array) #1 /home/m22/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(101): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->process('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save', Array) #2 /home/m22/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(322): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver->resolve() #3 /home/m22/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(239): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest() #4 /home/m22/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #5 /home/m22/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array) #6 /home/m22/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #7 /home/m22/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array) #8 /home/m22/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #9 /home/m22/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() #10 /home/m22/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() #11 /home/m22/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor)) #12 {main}" }
```

anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue with your data , your data is already in json format and below you are still doing **json_encode** that's the issue. Removed **json_encode** from there it will resolve this issue.

Try below updated code :

```
<?php 

$productData =  '{
  "product": {
    "sku": "test1",
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "localisation",
        "value": "Test Description"
      }
    ]
  }
}';       


                $token = getToken();
                $str = "http://m22.example.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/test1";

                $ch = curl_init($str);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$productData); //json_encode removed from here             

                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " .$token)); // also for token as well no need to do json_encode as token is only single string so

                $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
                echo "goes here in result";
                print_r($result);
                exit;
?>
```